# Sequence limits

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $lim(x_n)=x$. Show from first principles that $x_n$ is eventually equal to $x$.

I started by just defining the lim.
For $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t. $n\ge N$ implies that $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$.
Is it correct to say that since $x_n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x_n$ has to converge to a number in $\mathbb{Z}$? And since $x_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ then for  $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ to be true, $x_n$ has to be equal to $x$.

I'm not sure if I approached the right way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is essentially asking you to prove that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.  So, you probably shouldn't assume it.  You might want to ask what happens if $\epsilon =\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If $\varepsilon =1/2$, then we have $|x_n-x|<1/2$. Where should I go from there? $|x_n-x|<1/2$ can still be satisfied if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x_n\ne x$. How can I prove that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Prove that from some $n>N$, $x_n=x$.

Comment: There is at most one integer that is within $\frac{1}{2}$ of any real number.  So, let $z$ be that integer.  Now set $\epsilon =|x-z|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a convergent sequence of integers. Assume contrary, suppose that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. Then, by definition limit of a sequence,

$$\displaystyle(\forall\epsilon>0),(\exists N\in\mathbb{N}),(\forall n\geq N):(|x_n-x|<\epsilon) $$

In particular, one can pick  $\epsilon=\min\{ \lceil x \rceil-x \ , \  x-\lfloor x \rfloor \}$, clearly that $\epsilon>0$. But, as $x_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ by the denition of ceiling and 
floor functions, we have that $|x_n-x|\geq \lceil x \rceil-x \ \  $ **or** $ \ \ |x_n-x|\geq x-\lfloor x \rfloor$, that is $|x_n-x|\geq \epsilon$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and that is the contradiction! Therefore, $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.